# Oracle VirtualBox focus not changing

Tags: virtualbox, window, focus

I run VirtualBox in many environments and in Ubuntu this is the only place where I have come across this bug

I've installed the latest VirtualBox and this problem still persists, it's odd

Basically it's when you have a VM open with the display as full screen when you click on the minimise button on the options menu, the place where you can select to install guest additions from you see the VM minimise animation go off to the launcher but then when you move the mouse focus goes back to the minimised VM once you click on it again focus goes back to your desktop

I'm currently running Ubuntu 13.04 but I happens with 12.10 as well

If you need further detail maybe I'll be able to post a video of it, I think what I'd like to know is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a Unity issue.  Can you boot into another desktop to test?

Comment: It is! I installed Gnome Shell and it doesn't happen anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since my deduction was accurate, I'll make it an answer.)

Sounds like a Unity issue. See if it happens in Gnome Shell.

:D

Here's a link to a desktop resource that Spence found: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Can you add the link I found in my answer to your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tony suggests

> Sounds like a Unity issue. Can you boot into another desktop to test?

I installed Gnome Shell and when I use VirtualBox the *really* annoying screen focus bug has gone

I found a really good resource for available desktops here: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

As much as I like Unity I dislike this bug more, so I'll be using Gnome Shell until it's fixed, or I find a nicer one than Gnome Shell that doesn't have this bug with VirtualBox